# How to set two global objects returned from a function in JS?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm super new to Javascript and Jest and I have this code:

```
const foo = () => {
  const fun = //some function
  const obj = //some object
  //...
  return {fun, obj};
}

describe('Battery test', () =>
  let fun = ()=>{};
  let obj = {};
  beforeEach(() => {
    {fun, obj} = foo();
  }
}
```

This generate the error:

```
Unexpected token

  > 36 |         {fun, obj} = foo();
       |                    ^
```

The only (super ugly) workaround that came to my mind is:

```
describe('Battery test', () =>
  let fun = ()=>{};
  let obj = {};
  beforeEach(() => {
    const wrapper = foo();
    fun = wrapper.fun;
    obj = wrapper.obj;
  }
}
```

There is any other way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
 ({fun, obj} = foo());
```

Object destructuring needs to be distuinguished from the block statement.